# How do I run another Android application/activity in a window inside my app

Tags: android, android-activity, subapplication

What I want to do is be able to start another Android sub application (which I have not written myself) to run inside a window within my main application. I would want certain touch events etc on the elements of the main app that are still visible to allow me to stop the sub application.

I've found examples of how to launch another activity using an Intent - but I have found nothing allowing me to specify that it runs in a certain window.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if anyone knows how to do this on stock Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window metaphor does not exist under normal Android.

Some tablet makers have added it to their builds, but using windows would reduce the portability of your app.

Comment: Portability is not an issue for us as this would be running on very specific Android hardware. I'm now wondering if taking over the status bar and using that as the part of my main app that stays visible is a possible solution.